# Including an optional navigation property, where the navigation property Id is the same as the entity's primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I'm having an issue creating a query (well, I can create the query, but Entity Framework aborts it when trying to load the properties).

I have two entities: Contact and ExternalContactExtension.

**Contact**

ContactId

IsInternal

... some other data ...

**ExternalContactExtension**

ContactId

... some other data...

Now, the contactId is the same in both tables, but not all Contacts are external contacts (designated by the IsInternal) and have an external contact extension.

So the issue is when I run a query and try to include the external contact extension. Since ContactId is both the primary key and the foreign key, it's not nullable. I think EF takes that to mean it exists (even though on the navigation property it's listed at Zero or One). This is causing my queries to be aborted if I have any internal contacts who have no external contact extension.

Is there any way around this? Or do I have to grab the external contact extension entity separately?

**Edit:** Picture of my models:

[image]

Query that fails (generally more filtering/includes, but having the include ExternalContactExtension is the only thing that seems to determine if it fails):

```
            DataSupplier.GetMany<Contact>(
                x => x.Active,
                x => x.ExternalContactExtension

                ).ToList();
```

GetMany definition (technically, called by an intermediary class, but that's just passing on the parameters):

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetMany<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        IDbSet<TEntity> set = this.context.Set<TEntity>();

        var query = set.IncludeMultiple(includeProperties).AsQueryable<TEntity>();

        query = query.Where(where);
        this.queryString = "";
        this.queryString = query.ToString();
        List<TEntity> list = query.ToList();
        return list;
    }
```

Error Message:

[image]

It doesn't actually throw any messages until you try to use the properties (then I get a null reference exception).

**Another edit:**

I did a SQL profile and EF is correctly generating the SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ContactId] AS [ContactId], 
[Extent1].[EmployeeId] AS [EmployeeId], 
[Extent1].[IsInternal] AS [IsInternal], 
[Extent1].[GroupId] AS [GroupId], 
[Extent1].[OldSupplierId] AS [OldSupplierId], 
[Extent1].[Active] AS [Active], 
[Extent1].[InsertUserId] AS [InsertUserId], 
[Extent1].[InsertDate] AS [InsertDate], 
[Extent1].[UpdateUserId] AS [UpdateUserId], 
[Extent1].[UpdateDate] AS [UpdateDate], 
[Extent2].[ContactId] AS [ContactId1], 
[Extent2].[Salutation] AS [Salutation], 
[Extent2].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent2].[MiddleInitial] AS [MiddleInitial], 
[Extent2].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent2].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
[Extent2].[Fax] AS [Fax], 
[Extent2].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent2].[Department] AS [Department], 
[Extent2].[Email] AS [Email], 
[Extent2].[Address] AS [Address], 
[Extent2].[City] AS [City], 
[Extent2].[Territory] AS [Territory], 
[Extent2].[Country] AS [Country]
FROM  [DataSupplier].[Contact] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [DataSupplier].[ExternalContactExtension] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ContactId] = [Extent2].[ContactId]
WHERE [Extent1].[Active] = 1
```

(It correctly is doing an outer join, and this SQL does return the correct results/it runs). So it's somewhere where Entity Framework is doing the processing that's breaking it.

Comment: Are you sure the navigation property is set up With "0..1" on `Contact` and "1" on `ExternalContactExtension`?  If so, please include more information about the queries being aborted - stack trace, exact error message, etc.

Comment: Nice update!  Does it work if you take out out the `x => x.ExternalContactExtension` line?  Or does it still abort?

Comment: @Bobson It works if I take out the line, does not work if that line is in there. This is actually the whittled down version of a much larger query (and including that line causes it to abort). The includes work for other properties on that query.

Comment: I'm suspecting `set.IncludeMultiple()` isn't handling it right.  But `ExternalContactExtensionID` (what I assume the field is named) should be nullable, too, just in case it's not.

Comment: @Bobson That's the problem. In Contact, ContactId is the primary key and it's an identity field. ExternalContactExtension uses ContactId as it's primary key. (So a contact with Contact with ContactId 5 could have an external contact extension with ContactId 5. But for a different contact (which is internal) might have ContactId 7, but there wouldn't be an external contact extension with ContactId 7 because Contact 7 isn't an external contact. Therefore, ContactId in the Contact entity is both the primary key and the foreign key, so it can't be nullable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33159/discussion-between-bobson-and-corrugatedair)

Comment: What is `externalContacts` in the screenshot you are showing? Is it the result collection of the query, i.e. a collection of `Contacts`?

Comment: @Slauma That was just the variable name I used. It is a collection of contacts. The line of code was: 

var externalContacts =DataSupplier.GetMany<Contact>(x => x.Active,x => x.ExternalContactExtension).ToList();

Comment: I see. It's strange. The relationship is a rather standard one-to-one relationship (with shared primary key) which is supported by EF and "usually" works. Is the SQL on the bottom of your question the *complete* SQL or did you extract only this part from an actually larger query?

Comment: @Slauma It's the complete SQL from the query that's listed there. I think the issue though is that it's not strictly a 1-1 ... it's a 1-0..1. If I create a query where all of the entities being returned have external contact extensions, it's fine. If they don't have it, that's when it breaks.

Comment: But *optional* one-to-(one or zero) relationships are standard as well. That's why there is a left outer join. The navigation property should just be `null` if a contact does not have an extension. Does your model come from a DB-first workflow? Or code-first or model-first?

Comment: @Slauma That's true. We're doing database first.

Comment: Maybe it won't really help, but I would open a new (general C#/Visual Studio/Debugger) question and ask what to do and how to find more details of a problem, if 1) your code doesn't throw an exception and 2) when you drill into an `IEnumerable` in the debugger on every item you get a message like *Function evaluation was aborted.* or *Cannot dereference expression. The pointer is not valid.* I have no clue what this means.

Comment: @Slauma I think I'm going to do that because on closer inspection, this seems to work fine if I don't step through and debug. But if I debug and I try to view the entities, that gets me the error message and actually kills the entire process. It's very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the chat, the best way to solve this might be to create the "missing" `ExternalContactExtensionID` field which can be `NULL`.

You can do that with only a minor tweak to the database. Create a calculated field and use the formula:

```
CASE WHEN IsExternal THEN ContactID ELSE NULL END
```

Then EF will see what it's expecting, and it should all be good.